# unzip() fails using install_github

Tags: r

A number of people in my team are having issues installing packages from Github using `install_github` on Windows 7 Enterprise. However, I do not have these issues on the same build. For example, when trying to install `readr`, they see the following:

```
> devtools::install_github("hadley/readr")
Using GitHub PAT from envvar GITHUB_PAT
Downloading GitHub repo hadley/readr@master
from URL https://api.github.com/repos/hadley/readr/zipball/master
Error in utils::unzip(src, exdir = target) : 
  cannot open file 'C:/Users/XXXXX/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpYVS4zi/devtools23d42e596b7c/tidyverse-readr-b8c3ddb/R/POSIXct.R': No such file or directory
```

They have write access to the TMP folder into which these files are being extracted.

Interestingly enough when they download the zip directly from Github's website and try to extract into their user folder, they get the same behaviour from Winzip, but 7-zip can successfully unpack the file.

Does anyone know what might be causing this behaviour?

Comment: Please try having your team members run R in admin mode.  This is just a hunch, but perhaps R itself does not have rights to a certain location in non admin mode.

Comment: Works fine for me on Windows 10 and R 3.3.2. What version of R are they using?

Comment: update package `devtools` and check it is OK by running `devtools::dr_devtools()`

Comment: My team has local admin rights and have write access to the temp file directory - I dont think its this. Also, this has been a problem for ~1y, but haven't had the time to look into this until now so this has been a problem that has persisted for them across R / devtools versions

Answer (score 0):

Try running
`options(unzip = "internal")`
before running `devtools::install_github`. 
This has worked for me in the past, not sure why.

Comment: OK sorry dude, that has worked for me before on Windows 7 Professional.